# Is it possible to set accessibility labels on system provided UIActivity items in UIActivityViewController?

Tags: swift, xcode, accessibility, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiaccessibility

When I use Accessibility Inspector to inspect the reminders and more buttons in the UIActivityViewController their labels are both simply "Activity". Is it possible to change these labels?

I don't see anywhere in the documentation where you can get a reference to the system provided UIShareGroupActivityCell items.

[image] [image]

Comment: If you turn on Voice Over on a real iOS device you will get the expected result. The Reminders activity says "Reminders". The "More..." button says "More". In other words, there is nothing you need to do here.

Comment: @HangarRash this for automated testing, so we need access to the accessibilityLabel